# Dockle tells about error CIS-DI-0010 in my Dockerfile (nginx image)

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, cicd

When I check my docker image with Dockle, I get a FATAL error:

FATAL   - CIS-DI-0010: Do not store credential in environment variables/files
* Suspicious ENV key found : NGINX_GPGKEY on /bin/sh -c set -x     && addgroup --system --gid 101 nginx     && adduser --system --disabled-login --ingroup nginx --no-create-home --home /nonexistent --gecos "nginx user" --shell /bin/false --uid 101 nginx     && apt-get update     && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y gnupg1 ca-certificates     &&     NGINX_GPGKEY=573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62;     found='';     for server in         hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80         pgp.mit.edu     ; do         echo "Fetching GPG key $NGINX_GPGKEY from $server";         apt-key adv --keyserver "$server" --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys "$NGINX_GPGKEY" && found=yes && break;     done;     test -z "$found" && echo >&2 "error: failed to fetch GPG key $NGINX_GPGKEY" && exit 1;     apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove -y gnupg1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"     && nginxPackages="         nginx=${NGINX_VERSION}-${PKG_RELEASE}         nginx-module-xslt=${NGINX_VERSION}-${PKG_RELEASE}         nginx-module-geoip=${NGINX_VERSION}-${PKG_RELEASE}         nginx-module-image-filter=${NGINX_VERSION}-${PKG_RELEASE}         nginx-module-njs=${NGINX_VERSION}+${NJS_VERSION}-${PKG_RELEASE}     "     && case "$dpkgArch" in         amd64|arm64)             echo "deb https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ bullseye nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list             && apt-get update             ;;         *)             echo "deb-src https://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ bullseye nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list                         && tempDir="$(mktemp -d)"             && chmod 777 "$tempDir"                         && savedAptMark="$(apt-mark showmanual)"                         && apt-get update             && apt-get build-dep -y $nginxPackages             && (                 cd "$tempDir"                 && DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS="nocheck parallel=$(nproc)"                     apt-get source --compile $nginxPackages             )                         && apt-mark showmanual | xargs apt-mark auto > /dev/null             && { [ -z "$savedAptMark" ] || apt-mark manual $savedAptMark; }                         && ls -lAFh "$tempDir"             && ( cd "$tempDir" && dpkg-scanpackages . > Packages )             && grep '^Package: ' "$tempDir/Packages"             && echo "deb [ trusted=yes ] file://$tempDir ./" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/temp.list             && apt-get -o Acquire::GzipIndexes=false update             ;;     esac         && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y                         $nginxPackages                         gettext-base                         curl     && apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list         && if [ -n "$tempDir" ]; then         apt-get purge -y --auto-remove         && rm -rf "$tempDir" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/temp.list;     fi     && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log     && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log     && mkdir /docker-entrypoint.d (You can suppress it with --accept-key)

And,
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

WORKDIR /

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    libfcgi-dev \
    spawn-fcgi \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN chmod 777 /var/cache/nginx/ /var/run/

COPY server/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
COPY server/hello.c /etc/nginx/
COPY server/span-fcgi.sh /etc/nginx/

RUN chmod +x /etc/nginx/span-fcgi.sh \
    && gcc -o /etc/nginx/hello.fcgi /etc/nginx/hello.c -lpthread -lfcgi \
    && usermod -aG root,gnats,daemon,disk,sudo nginx

EXPOSE 81

USER nginx

CMD ["/etc/nginx/span-fcgi.sh"]
```

The script "span-fcgi.sh" contains

```
#!/bin/bash  
spawn-fcgi -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8080 -f /etc/nginx/hello.fcgi -F 1  
nginx -g 'daemon off;
```

Please, tell what is going in my Dockerfile, that makes the Dockle to show error above? How solve the problem and silence Dockle?

Answer (score 1):

you can bypass this by using the -ak or --accept-key flag. More documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/goodwithtech/dockle#accept-suspicious-environment-variables--files--file-extensions).

```
dockle -ak NGINX_GPGKEY [IMAGE_NAME]
```